# How NOT to delete the database after reinstall or uninstall application - sqllite, SugarOrm

Tags: android

How NOT to delete the database after reinstall or uninstall application - sqllite, SugarOrm. I want keep data even after uninstall application on reinstall. Is it possible? Is it enough to change the path to the database or I need to change something more?
SugarDb sugarDb = new SugarDb(getApplicationContext()); new
File(sugarDb.getDB().getPath())

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that would only be possible if you had some login or lookup based on the device ID to look up and download said database from your server. In other words, upon user uninstall all the app and data are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a small amount of data, Auto Backup will do it.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

Otherwise you're going to need to do your own cloud backup solution to get this done.  The entire point of uninstalling an app is deleting all associated data, you'd need to jump through some hoops and expose those files to get around it.